# Window postMessage wait for eventListener ready

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I have a browser extension, that executes content scripts for the top window and iframes and the iframes (sub-iframes) inside the iframes. The top window generates random numbers and assigns those numbers to each iframe with window.postMessage method and for the sub-iframes their parents generate the random number and sends to them with the same method. But, sometimes, the iframes and sub-iframes don't get the message from their parent and my suspicion is the eventListener for those messages inside the iframes are not ready yet, when their parents trying to send the message.

I think it might look clearer if I give an example.

This is how the content script looks when they receive a message:

```
function receivedMessage(e){
    console.log("The random number is:", e.data.rndm);
}

if (window.top != window.self){

    console.log("Window is iframe");

    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener("message", receivedMessage, false);
    }else{
        window.attachEvent("onmessage", receivedMessage);
    }
}else{
    console.log("Window is top, no assigned random number");
}
```

For sending the messages for example:

```
let win = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow;

win.postMessage({ "rndm" : "1234"}, '*');
```

My question is how could I make this win.postMessage() to wait until the window.addEventListener worked inside that window (iframe or sub-iframe) and onmessage listener is ready there? The solution should also work for crossOrigin iframes.

This is how manifest.json for content scripts look:

```
"content_scripts" : [
 {
 "js": ["ext/jquery-2.1.4.min.js",
        "lib/gen_helper.js", 
        "a.js"
        ],
 "run_at": "document_start",
 "all_frames" : true,
 "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
 }
```

The main purpose of sending those random numbers to the iframes was, I wanted them to have unique numbers that I could use in the background script and in the top window. In the chrome extension when you use onHeadersReceived method you can find the frameId which the headers are for.

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
  function(details) {


       console.log(details.frameId);
       console.log(details.parentFrameId);

 }, filter, [  "responseHeaders"]);
```

But that frameId is not available in the front-end, I couldn't find them in the content script. Looks like they are only available in the background script.

Comment: I don't think the event listener needs to be "ready". The messages should be saved until the event listener is added.

Comment: What could be the problem that those iframes are not getting the message from the parent?

Comment: I added the manifest.json content_script related section to the question. They all work for document_start and all_frames. I can see from the log that eventually all scripts are injected to the frames.

Comment: So it may be a bug in Chrome or an inherent deficiency. The usual solution is to initiate the handshake from an iframe i.e. do parent.postMessage(). Or keep your current approach and add a confirmation so if the iframe doesn't send a message with the same id back within 100ms you would retry.