# Is Window.postMessage susceptible to race conditions?

Tags: javascript, race-condition, postmessage

MDN's examples for [`Window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) include:

> ```js
> const popup = window.open(/* popup details */);
>
> // When the popup has fully loaded, if not blocked by a popup blocker:
>
> // This does nothing, assuming the window hasn't changed its location.
> popup.postMessage(
>   "The user is 'bob' and the password is 'secret'",
>   "https://secure.example.net"
> );
> ```

This is as I would have expected: that you need to wait for the target window to register its [`message` event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/message_event) before calling `postMessage`. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to do that. (Maybe something with `my_iframe.contentWindow.addEventListener`, if that's even possible?)

I *did*, however, find [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/117000509) suggesting you *don't* need to do that:

> I don't think the event listener needs to be "ready". The messages should be saved until the event listener is added. – [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) [Feb 12, 2021 at 20:11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66178418/window-postmessage-wait-for-eventlistener-ready#comment117000509_66178418)

Which is it? *Do* we need to wait for the event handler to be registered, or *don't* we?

Comment: The [standard document](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-messaging.html#posting-messages) seems to suggest that a message event sent to a page without a handler won't be received, but the wording of the Note section is not very clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is trivial to test.

```js
const addMessageListener = () => {
    addEventListener("message", (event) => {
        console.log("Recieved: " + event.data);
    });
}

const sendMessage = (message) => {
    console.log("Sending: " + message);
    postMessage(message, '*');
};

const wait = () => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 500));

const actions = async () => {
    sendMessage("Sent before adding listener");
    await wait();
    sendMessage("Sent IMMEDIATELY before adding listener");
    addMessageListener();
    sendMessage("Sent after adding listener");
}

actions();
```

Messages are not queued waiting for a listener to be added, but synchronous code **might** block a message (the *Sent IMMEDIATELY* one in this example) being sent until a listener is added which could give the *illusion* of such a queue. That isn't behaviour you should depend on.

---

> that you need to wait for the target window to register its message event handler before calling postMessage. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to do that.

The approach I would take would be to add a message listener to the **opener** which, when it gets a suitable message, will start sending messages to the document in the new window. Then the document (whose URL you pass to `window.open`) can send `window.opener.postMessage("I am ready to accept your messages", origin)` once it has set up its own event listener.